# Assigning to a slice of a 3D array using the range operator

Tags: arrays, perl, slice

I have a 3 dimensional array. I want to set three elements of it like this:

```
$array[$x][$y][0 .. 2] = (0, 1, 2);
```

but perl tells me:

> Useless use of a constant (1) in void context

In array context:

```
@array[$x][$y][0 .. 2] = (0, 1, 2);
```

but perl tells me:

> syntax error near "]["

presumably meaning that it expects me to give it two indices and then assign to the third dimension as a separate array? However, on [this page](https://affy.blogspot.com/p5be/ch04.htm), under `Example: Assignment Using Array Slices`, it suggests that it is possible to assign to a slice using the range operator where it says:

```
@array1[1..3] = @array2[23..25];
```

How can I assign to a slice of the array like this, or do I have to assign each index individually?

Comment: http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to dereference the inner array:

```
@{ $arr[$x][$y] }[ 0 .. 2 ] = (0, 1, 2);
```

Comment: Why does the range operator return a reference?

Comment: Oh, I had a typo in the reply. Check it again: the `$arr[$x][$y]` is a reference.

Answer (score 4):

`$array[$x][$y][0..2]` isn't a slice; it's just an element lookup.

When you attempted to change it into a slice, you sliced the wrong array. You sliced `@arr` instead of `@{ $arr[$x][$y] }`.

The key here is to realize that there's no such thing as 3d arrays in Perl. What you have is an array of references to arrays of references to array, which is colloquially called array of array of array, and often abbreviated to AoAoA.

Array slices have the following syntax:

- `@NAME[LIST]`
- `@BLOCK[LIST]`
- `@$REF[LIST]`
- `EXPR->@[LIST]`<sup>[1]</sup>

You could use any of the following:

- The first syntax can't be used since the array to slice doesn't have a name.
- `@{ $array[$x][$y] }[0..2] = 0..2;`
- `my $ref = $array[$x][$y];  @$ref[0..2] = 0..2;`
- `$array[$x][$y]->@[0..2] = 0..2;`<sup>[1]</sup>

See [Dereferencing Syntax](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=977408).

---

1. Requires Perl 5.24+. Available in Perl 5.20+ by adding both `use feature qw( postderef );` and `no warnings qw( experimental::postderef );`.